# How can we implement 301 redirects for the below scenario on .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

Old url: [www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/businessline/product.html#/fundDetail/wholesale/portId=8162](http://www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/businessline/product.html#/fundDetail/wholesale/portId=8162)

New URL: [www.vanguard.com.au/businessline/products/en/detail/8162/Overview](http://www.vanguard.com.au/businessline/products/en/detail/8162/Overview)

We have 60 old urls of same pattern but only the portId will be changing in every url. Could someone please suggest how can we implement a generic redirect which will redirects all 60 old urls to new url (taking the portId value from old url) for this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RewriteRule in your `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^businessline/products/en/detail/([0-9]+)/Overview www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/businessline/product.html#/fundDetail/wholesale/portId=$1 [NE,L,NC,R=301]
```

If the `portid` perameter contains alphanumeric characters then change the regex pattern to `([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)` .

This redirect your new URL to the old one. If you are looking for a way to redirect your old URLs to the new one with fregment `#` then you will need to use a client side redirect like JavaScript as `#` redirection can not be implemented by using RewriteRule or  any  other server side redirect.